# ResultSet's getString method is messy in javafx. It's not in order

Tags: java

I get data from access database but they are not in column order.

[image][image]
[image]

I tried to put them in the order 1,2,3,4,5 and they are messed up, I have to fix like the picture above to display properly.

I really don't understand why.

Comment: code as text , not pictures. please

Comment: Don’t post pictures of code, for all the [very obvious reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Conversely and additionally, text as text, not as code :-)

Comment: If you want columns in a specific order, specify the column names explicitly in your select statement (which, BTW, is a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try `ResultSet#findColumn(String)` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn(java.lang.String))

Alternatively, you can use `ResultSet#getString(String)` by providing the column name instead of the index:

```
rs.getString("maSearch");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the values by column name instead.

Select * usually returns columns in order but I am unfamiliar with Access database, you could try selecting all columns instead of using *.